# Extract String property of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have several objects in an array which looks like this:

```
var objectArray = [
   abc: {id: "qq09qed0000", status: "running"}, 
   def: {id: "qq09qed0001", status: "paused"}, 
   ...
   xyz: {id: "qq09qed9999", status: "paused"}
];
```

EDIT: I am not sure, how it is represented in memory, the objectArray is created by doing array.push(object); several hundred times in a loop. The above is just an example to show you what the objects look like, they are truncated and in reality have lots more fields. Please stop telling me that the array is formatted wrong, it is, I am aware, it is just an example. The main thing to consider is how to go from an **array of objects** to an **array of strings**.

Edit2: Perhaps it looks like this in memory:

```
var objectArray = [
       {id: "qq09qed0000", status: "running"}, 
       {id: "qq09qed0001", status: "paused"}, 
       ...
       {id: "qq09qed9999", status: "paused"}
    ];
```

If I wanted an ordered array of just the ids (they are non sequential) of all of these elements, what would be the best way to extract them?

I have attempted a foreach loop,

```
for(var obj in objectArray ) {
    dataArray.push(objectArray[obj].getid());
}
```

But I am told this is not guarranteed to keep the ordering intact.

Comment: If you actually have an array, as in your code after your edit, then the ordering will be intact. Who told you that it wouldn't be?

Comment: What *exactly* is `objectArray`?  The code currently in the question is a syntax error.  It's not valid code.

Comment: you want to keep the order of the objectArray?

Comment: @ThorstenArtner'Austria' yes, I need an array of strings, that are in the same order that the objects are in the original array

Comment: _"Perhaps it looks like this in memory:"_:... **"Perhaps"**? Just log the variable and give us some facts. This is a problem we can help you with, but only if you tell us what the data is formatted as.

Comment: _The above is just an example to show you what the objects look like_ That is impossible

Comment: Would it help if I remove the example array? All that needs to be known is that there is an array or objects, the objects contain certain fields and I needed to extract one in particular and collect them up. I just wanted to show that graphically, instead of just using words. Geez folks. Would you all like to comment on any particular spelling mistakes too? perhaps I missed a comma or a full stop somewhere? Which would make the question invalid, and thus unanswerable.

Comment: I've posted a working solution for you. Check it at the bottom. I was down-voted twice because it had jquery in it, but I've made it pure javascript. See below...

Answer (score 0):

You can use maybe arr.sort() function

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Not on objects. Only on arrays.

Comment: If you look at the site I have posted you can see "the Objects can be sorted given the value of one of their properties" statement

Comment: __Arrays of objects__ can be sorted, yes. Plain objects can't. However, it seems like the OP made a typo in the question. -1 removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sortById (a,b) 
  {
  if (a.id < b.id) return -1
  if (a.id > b.id) return 1;
  return 0;
  }

objectArray.sort (sortById);
```

Comment: Objects don't have the `.sort` function.

Comment: `objectArray` is not an array according to their snippet (although the name is misleading)

Comment: It seems like the OP made a typo in the question. -1 removed.

Comment: whats the problem, o i see he called it dataArray.ok then dataArray.sort (sortById), but referencing the tems of objectArray not direct id

Answer (score 0):

Your `objectArray` is an object, not an array, and as such, has no obvious / defined ordering.

What order the elements are in, depends on the JavaScipt implementation of the browser it's running in.

For that reason, there is no way to *"keep the ordering intact."*, since there is no set ordering in the first place.

Now that you've edite the question, the `objectArray` isn't valid JavaScript syntax.

Arrays can't have key:value pairs like this:

```
var objectArray = [
    abc: {id: "qq09qed0000", status: "running"},
```

---

From what I gathered from your question, this should work:

```
data = data2.map(function(e){return e.id;});
```

This should return an array with only `id` values, in the same order as in `data2`.

Comment: Apologies, I used {} instead of []. It is definitely an array in my code.

Comment: [] (array) cannot have keys like you do in your example.

Comment: The code I posted is just a representation of how the object is created, at one point in the code, we do array.push() and inject hundreds of objects into an array. Don't take the example too literally, I DEFIFITELY have an array of objects. Whats the best way to extract strings from those objects and keep them in the correct order?

Comment: @Husman: Then show us the EXACT data format that `objectArray` contains. That information is __very significant__ in how to manipulate it.

Comment: @Husman Then we cannot answer your question, we are providing solutions to a problem given to us.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like it is working, but will have to go through QA who will put it through their Selenium test, before I can comment on if it is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

If you push all the ids in an array first, then sort them after, the fact that the 'for' function does not keep the ordering won't matter

Push all the ids in a new array

```
var objectArray = {
    abc: {id: "qq09qed0000", status: "running"}, 
    def: {id: "qq09qed0001", status: "paused"}, 
    ...
    xyz: {id: "qq09qed9999", status: "paused"}
};

var idArray = [];
for(var item in objectArray){

    idArray.push(item.id);
};
```

This will produce an array looking like this:

```
idsArray = ["qq09qed0000","qq09qed0001", ..., "qq09qed9999"]
```

Next, sort the array using the array sort method

```
idsArray.sort();
```

OR

```
idsArray.sort(function(a,b){
    return a - b;
});
```

This will sort them in alphanumeric order by default. You can also reverse the order using:

```
idsArray.sort(function(a,b){
    return b - a;
});
```

Comment: This question isn't tagged with jQuery.

Comment: -1 jQuery is not needed for something this simple. This also does not sort the ids.

Comment: I've removed the jQuery reference and added the sorting.

Comment: You can't use `a - b` to sort strings.

Answer (score -1):

```
Namespace.pluck = function(obj, prop)
{
    var isFunction = Namespace.isFunction(prop);
    return Namespace.map(obj, function(key, element)
    {
        return isFunction ? prop(element) : element[prop];
    });
};

var ids = Namespace.pluck(objectArray, 'id').sort();
```

Array.prototype.sort() will give you a lexicographical sort, and not a natural sort. 10 will come after 1 but before 2

Comment: `TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

Comment: You have to implement 'isFunction' and 'map', they are standard implementations.

Comment: Don't assume people know that. Always include necessary code in your answer.

Comment: 'pluck', 'map', and 'isFunction' (or something similar) are all standard constructs. I think it's fine to assume programmers know what they do/how to implement them...failing that Google is a few keypresses away :)

Comment: You forget that a lot of programmers on SO are just getting started programming. **Always** provide **all** necessary information for a answer to work.